# SocketTimeoutException crash in android

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2 for making API requests in the Android app. This is the code block for making API requests:

```
    // retrofit setup

        val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        val okHttpClient = okHttpClientBuilder.build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

        var searchService = retrofit.create(ISearchAPI::class.java)

   // make API request

   try {
        response = searchService.getWaste(currentLanguage, searchTerm)
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        Log.d("RequestFailed", "Request failed.")
    }
```

The problem that I am facing is when there is a poor network, the request exceeds the connection timeout, and the app crashes. I don't want the app to crash but instead, I want to show a "Connection timeout" alert message to the user.

I have spent hours and days just to solve this issue but with no success. I found a blog post on [medium](https://hanru-yeh.medium.com/fix-sockettimeoutexception-on-retrofit-with-coroutine-9fa0d15d2d7f) but their workaround only checks if there is no internet connection but does not work for poor connection. I also tried adding an interceptor as discussed in the workaround section in the medium tutorial as follows but still, it's not able to catch exceptions and it crashes.

```
// adding interceptor
fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
    return connectivityManager?.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected == true
}
class ConnectVerifierInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        if (!isNetworkAvailable() {
            throw IOException("No Network Available!")
        }
        val request = chain.request()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .addInterceptor(ConnectVerifierInterceptor())
    .build()

val server = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(XXXX).client(okHttpClient).create(APIServer::class.java)
```

Isn't there any solution for this problem in android?

Comment: have you tried adding another catch block for SocketTimeOutException?

Comment: Yes I have tried adding try catch block in retrofit setup if I understand what you mean but the problem is same. It does not get inside catch block. It just crashes.

Comment: Not at the retrofit set up but at making api request?

Comment: If that doesn't work you need to add interceptor by adding a Http client in the retrofit. Interceptor will handle the exception and will return the fake response on socket timeout exception.

Comment: @VivekGupta, thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with sample code for interceptor. I have also tried adding an interceptor as discussed in the medium tutorial (link in the question) but still crashes with exception. Idk if thats how the interceptor is to be implemented.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? @skJosh . I forgot to add the answer, will add soon if you didn't resolve this.

Comment: @VivekGupta, yes thanks. I am able to resolve the issue. Found that I have to add try catch block inside the interceptor.